# abide + direct object?

Tags: grammaticality

[Sample Casebook #2 (2nd Edition) : Garratt v. Dailey, 279 P.2d 1091 | H2O](https://opencasebook.org/casebooks/1640-sample-casebook-2-2nd-edition/resources/1.2.1-garratt-v-dailey-279-p2d-1091/)

> The cause is remanded for clarification, with instructions to make definite findings on the issue of whether Brian Dailey knew with substantial certainty that the plaintiff would attempt to sit down where the chair which he moved had been, and to change the judgment if the findings warrant it.
>
> Costs on this appeal will **abide** the ultimate decision of the superior court. If a judgment is entered for the plaintiff, Ruth Garratt, appellant here, she shall be entitled to her costs on this appeal. If, however, the judgment of dismissal remains unchanged, the respondent will be entitled to recover his costs on this appeal.

I know ["abide" can stand alone as verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/38213), but this is a different case because "abide"  here has direct object. Why not ["abide by"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/114980) here?

Comment: abide is usually for people, not things.

Answer (score 1):

Legal use of abide:

Abide
**Black's Law Dictionary: 2nd Edition**
Definition:

> To "abide the order of the court" means to perform, execute or conform
> to such order. Jackson v. State, 30 Kan. 88, 1 Pac. 317; Hodge v.
> Hodgdon, 8 Cush. (Mass.) 294. See McGarry v. Sinte, 37 Kan. 9, 14 Pac.
> 492. A stipulation in an arbitration bond that the parties shall "abide by" the award of the arbitrators means only that they shall
> await the award of the arbitrators, without revoking the submission,
> and not that they shall acquiesce in the award when made. Marshall v.
> Reed, 48 N. EL 36 ; Shaw v. Hatch, 6 N. H. 162; Weeks v. Trask, 81 Me.
> 127, 16 Atl. 413, 2 In In A. 532.

Costs on this appeal will conform to the ultimate decision of the superior court. For example

Answer (score 0):

"Abide" can have the meaning of "wait patiently for":

> I will abide his arrival.

This use is rather rare, formal and dated, but it seems to have use in legal documents.  Here it means that no action is taken (on costs) until  the superior court makes its decision.